# PyQt5 QGraphicsItems in a QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene can't always be clicked on

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm having a problem where the clickable area of a `QGraphicsItem` isn't always consistent when I move / resize / rotate or otherwise change the way the `QGraphicsItem` is positioned on the scene.

I have a `QMainWindow` that only has a `QGraphicsView` with some layouts and a button. It's just saved in a ui file that was something quick thrown together with the Designer tool.

I create a `QGraphicsScene` and set that as the scene for my `QGraphicsView`. And I map a button to add an arrow to the `QGraphicsScene`.

```
UI_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui")
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(UI_FILE, self)
        self.scene  = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.graphicsView.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
        self.graphicsView.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.ViewportUpdateMode.BoundingRectViewportUpdate)
        self.button_mapping()
        
    def button_mapping(self):
        self.arrow_button.clicked.connect(self.addArrow)
    
    def addArrow(self):
        arrow_item = ArrowItem()
        self.scene.addItem(arrow_item)
```

The way the `ArrowItem` works is if you click and drag the arrow it should move within the scene, and the end and start points of the arrow can be changed by clicking and dragging the  "PointItem" which are circles on the ends of the arrow.

Here are my `ArrowItem` and `PointItem` classes.

```
class PointItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, point:QPointF, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setParentItem(parent)
        self.local_point  = point
        self.parent_point = self.mapToParent(point)
        self.radius = 10
        
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsEllipseItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable           , True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsEllipseItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable        , True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsEllipseItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def get_parent_point(self):
        return self.parent_point
    
    def set_parent_point(self, point:QPointF):
        self.parent_point = self.mapToParent(point)
    
    def get_local_point(self):
        return self.local_point
    
    def set_local_point(self, point:QPointF):
        self.local_point = point

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        top_left     = QPointF(self.local_point.x() - self.radius, self.local_point.y() + self.radius)
        bottom_right = QPointF(self.local_point.x() + self.radius, self.local_point.y() - self.radius)
        return QRectF(top_left, bottom_right)

    def shape(self) -> QPainterPath:
        return self.get_path()

    def get_path(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(self.local_point, self.radius, self.radius)
        return path

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.drawPath(self.get_path())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.set_local_point(event.pos())
        self.set_parent_point(event.pos())
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.set_local_point(event.pos())
        self.set_parent_point(event.pos())
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.set_local_point(event.pos())
        self.set_parent_point(event.pos())
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class ArrowItem(QGraphicsItem):
    '''
    Class to create Arrow Item
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.start_point = PointItem(QPointF(50,50)  , self)
        self.end_point   = PointItem(QPointF(100,100), self)
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable           , True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable        , True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
 
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.start_point.get_parent_point(), self.end_point.get_parent_point())

    def shape(self):
        path        = self.arrowPath()
        return path

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        painter.drawPath(self.shape())

        if self.isSelected():
            pen = QPen(QColor(255, 0, 0), 7, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine)
            brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
        else:
            pen = QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
            brush = QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,0))        
        
        path = self.arrowPath()

        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawPath(path)
        
        self.scene().update()

    def arrowPath(self):
        path        = QPainterPath()
        start_point = self.start_point.get_parent_point()
        end_point   = self.end_point.get_parent_point()
        path.moveTo(start_point)
        path.lineTo(end_point)
        arrow_head_size = 10
        diff = end_point - start_point
        angle = math.atan2(diff.y(), diff.x())
        self.arrow_p1 = end_point - QPointF(arrow_head_size * math.cos(angle - math.pi / 6), arrow_head_size * math.sin(angle - math.pi / 6))
        self.arrow_p2 = end_point - QPointF(arrow_head_size * math.cos(angle + math.pi / 6), arrow_head_size * math.sin(angle + math.pi / 6))
        path.lineTo(self.arrow_p1)
        path.moveTo(end_point)
        path.lineTo(self.arrow_p2)

        return path
```

This code works to change the arrow the way I would like and there are no dead spots before I change the geometry and position of the arrow. Once I change things, there are some dead spots where my mouse events aren't registering.

I thought from reading things online that the `shape()` method was what defined the clickable area, but that's not the behavior I'm seeing since I'm played around with the shape and nothing seems to help.

Is there something that I'm not updating when I change the dimensions or position of the arrow?

I added a `PointingHandCursor` to indicate when the cursor is in a spot where the mouse events will register so hovering my mouse over the object shows where the deadspots are before needing to click on anything.

Here's a short video of the behavior:
[image]